# Eclipse on mac: crash after clicking the Eclipse icon, reinstall but can't create view for pyDev

Tags: java, python, eclipse, macos

I have `pyDev` installed on `Eclipse`, but I quit the `eclipse` without saving `python` module yesterday. The Eclipse got crashed when I tried to open it. So I download the eclipse and install again. The new one can open java project and class, but for python, it said that: Could not create the view: `org.python.pydev.navigator.view`
No editor descriptor for id `org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor`
What can I do now? I didn't find anything useful till now.

Comment: Sounds like you have installed a version of Eclipse that does not have python development included, so you need to install that.